# Please tell me how to change the setting of the change value of the numerical slider

Tags: customization

Clicking the left or right button of the value slider changes the value by 0.1.

I want to change the numerical value of this change to something like 0.05 or 0.25.

I know that Ctrl and Shift can be set to 0.01 when dragging a slider.

I would like to change the setting for the size of the numerical value change when clicking the button instead of dragging.

I searched for preferences but couldn't find it.

If you know how, please let me know.
[image]